# Xcode Cloud: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-cloud

i'm new user with Xcode cloud. i'm begin with it today after connect with Xcode Cloud and build i'm get error like this:

```
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'

Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'
```

and

```
could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig' in search paths
Release.xcconfig:2

could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths
Release.xcconfig:3
```

in my local. everything work well.

[image: this is error log in Xcode Cloud]

Answer (score 0):

This is a CocoaPods related error. If it works correctly locally, the error should be on XcodeCloud and should be resolved with ci_post_clone.sh.

In my case:

1. create ci_post_clone.sh
2. put pod deintegrate and pod update in ci_post_clone.sh

This is how I was able to eliminate that error.

ci_post_clone.sh is a custom post-clone build script that Xcode Cloud runs after cloning a Git repository.

I used the following URL as a reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710440
- https://rodydavis.com/posts/flutter-and-xcode-cloud/

Flutter, but just in case, I will include a successful ci_post_clone.sh.

```
#!/bin/sh

# The default execution directory of this script is the ci_scripts directory.
cd $CI_WORKSPACE # change working directory to the root of your cloned repo.

# Install Flutter using git.
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b stable $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"


# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
flutter precache --ios

# Install Flutter dependencies.
flutter pub get

# Install CocoaPods using Homebrew.
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 # disable homebrew's automatic updates.
brew install cocoapods


cd ios
pod deintegrate
# Install CocoaPods dependencies.
pod update # run `pod install` in the `ios` directory.

flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
exit 0
```